# GroundOverlay google maps - image does not fill image bound

Tags: google-maps, kml

I try to show on google maps 
http://www.3d-islands.com/kml/mto/caraib/carib_ir.kml
This kml contains a GroundOverlay with a gif image, color and bound.
I tried with two map methodes:google.maps.KmlLayer(..) and with google.maps.GroundOverlay(..) to. Same result:
Image bound will be reserved on map, but image will be showed only on small map area begining from SW point. Not filled on full bound area.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your GIF has a bunch of extraneous space above and to the right of the actual image.  Either edit the GIF to remove the extra space or change the bounds to account for it.

------------------------ top of image ------------------
[image: raw image for GroundOverlay]
------------------------------- bottom of image ---------------

[example with cropped image](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160221_carib_ir_cropped.kml)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Exactly what I described in my question. This groundoverlay is showed perfect in google earth. Basically - groundoverlay principle: An image with any size will be extended to the given ImageBound and that not happend in google maps, but happend in google earth.

Comment: Next knowledge:
the questioned GIF looks so like image above. Useful info only a small part, the rest of image is transparent. 
Google eart shows only the useful part, google maps shows the full image. Content of image I cannot change! 
How can i get the useful layer in javascript?

Comment: Change the bounds to reflect the true size of the image.

Comment: The bound size is OK. Image is wrong! On GE is showed correctly

Comment: Then fix the image.  That is what I did, why can't you do that?

Comment: Image is generated by third server. I have only the image link:
http://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/real-time/mosaic/images/kml/tiles/yymmosaicir-e-3.GIF
and this is realtime image. I don't know if it is possible in javascript to split on gif frames?